# Flex Builder, keep flash player running on Error

Tags: debugging, flexbuilder, compilation, flash

I got this project, where there this error keeps occurring and its not on my table to fix it right now. I have other priorities. This error isn't that big deal as well for the rest of the project - but everytime this error gets thrown when I launched the debug player in Flex Builder, it shuts down the player right away.

Is it possible that I can turn off (temporarily) this 'action' of closing my flashplayer on Error so I can speed up my workflow.

It's getting to my nerves...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, the only way to stop that error would be to either fix it, or to use a non-debug version of the flash player.

Out of curiosity, what is the error you are getting?  And is the problem going to take very long to fix?

Comment: but if i run a non debug player, im not getting traces anymore

Comment: btw, its something in an intro that takes about 10 secs to play, and i have to wait untill the intro has finished before i can get deeper into the site :(

TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at home_fla::home_2/frame31()

Comment: I would go ahead and fix the problem, it really is the only way you are going to get rid of the error.  And if tracing is a requirement, you really don't have an option.  Unless like Christian says below you can temporarily put in a try/catch block.  But I would say just fix it.

Answer (score 0):

By "shuts down the player right away," do you mean the debugger responds to the uncaught exception?  If so, couldn't you just wrap the offending code in a try/catch block, to keep the debugger from halting, and go back to it later, maybe?